# CreateReadStream creates an extra newline delimiter in chunks?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a simple question on readStream in node's fs module. 
Here is the simple code:

```
fs = require('fs');
readStream = fs.createReadStream('somefile.d');
 readStream.on('data', function(chunk) {
 console.log(chunk.toString());
});
```

'somefile.d' is:

```
a1
a2
a3
a4
```

Question:
Why is there an extra newline at the end of the output? I tried an od -c to get an octal dump and yes there is an extra newline. Is that put by toString? 
**More importantly, why is chunk delimited by newline? The data event is triggered for every line.** I have not specified any option and there is no option to read chunks separated by any specific character. I know that there is the [carrier](https://github.com/pgte/carrier) module, for example, to get around this issue.

Any explanation will be appreciated.

~
~
~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure I fully understand, but if you're talking about the actual output of the program, as-written it looks like your only output is coming from `console.log`.  `console.log` terminates its write with a line ending.  If you want to write to stdout without a line terminator, you could just do:

`process.stdout.write(chunk)`

should send them out as-is.   You could also pipe the readstream directly to stdout if you wanted to:

`readStream.pipe(process.stdout);`

Comment: That totally explains the first part. I am accepting your answer because I just missed that simple point about console.log emitting a newline character at the end. But that does not explain why chunks are read, one line at a time, I mean delimited by newline. There is no such definition of chunk in node's streaming module and there is nothing to specify a different delimiter.  In this context, I understand the utility of the "carrier" module I have linked to, in my query.  Would appreciate an explanation on this point too...

Comment: No, afaik the chunk is some number of bytes, not delimited.  I don't have another explanation for you.

Comment: Thanks. I think that if size is not specified, it chunks until it sees a newline. My  guess...